# Cocos2d XNA CCApplication should be reference on Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame, cocos2d-x-for-xna

I try develop HelloWorld Game on Windows Phone 8 (VS 2013) with Cocos2D XNA + Monogame.
I install Monogame,create a project, add reference through Nuget on Cocos2d XNA.

Then i copy example from documentation https://cocos2dxna.codeplex.com

```
using System;
using Cocos2D;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace GameName3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
#if !WINDOWS && !MACOS
            this.graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
#else
            this.graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
#endif
            this.graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;

            // Frame rate is 30 fps by default for Windows Phone.
            TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
            IsFixedTimeStep = true;

#if WINDOWS || MACOS
            this.IsMouseVisible = true;
#endif
            CCApplication application = new AppDelegate(this, graphics);
            this.Components.Add(application);
            CCDirector.SharedDirector.GamePadEnabled = true;
            application.GamePadButtonUpdate += new CCGamePadButtonDelegate(application_GamePadButtonUpdate);
        }
```

On CCApplication I have that: Module 'Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Game, Version=4.0.0.0, Token=...' should be referenced.

But in MonoGame I have not found such a path...
I Also installed this https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230
What I Doing Wrong?

Comment: Do you have a reference to that assembly in your game project? (From the solution explorer: Project -> References -> check the list looking for Microsoft.XNA.Framework...

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21386287/screenshot.png Where I can find this dll?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D For a managed code project targeting Windows Phone 8, the Microsoft.Xna.Framework is already included as part of the reference: ".NET for Windows Phone". I tried use extern alias for Monogame.Framework extern alias MGF;

using System;
using Cocos2D;
using MGF::Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using MGF::Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework; but this not help...